# UITableViewCell reloading itself after being scrolled

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to make a UITableView. However my table fault is , when it is scrolled (When a cell is hides and then shows itself again) it resets the tabs and load the images from server again. How can i make it not load the images or retain the previous cell

```
static NSString *myIdentifier = @"myIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];


    backImage =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 4, 300, 62)];
    userDp    = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 10, 50, 50)];
    name            = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(67, 12, 176, 20)];

    name.font            = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaLTStd-Bold"   size:12];

CustomActivityViewer *imgIndicator = [[CustomActivityViewer alloc] initWithView:userDp];
[imgIndicator startAnimating];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),^{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", IMAGE_URL, player.imagePath]]]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [imgIndicator stopAnimating];
        if (img != nil)
            userDp.image = img;

        [imgIndicator stopAnimating];
    });
});

[name setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[name setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];
name.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.824 blue:0 alpha:1.0];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[cell.contentView addSubview:backImage];
[cell.contentView addSubview:userDp];
[cell.contentView addSubview:name];

return cell;
```

}

if i place if (cell!= nil) then cells repeat itself.

What to do?

P.S In one of the iPhone own tutorials i saw something like cell.contentView setting items with tags and then recalling views with tags if the cell is not nil. I have failed to find that tutorial. Just incase if anyone know

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html at `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` the reason why it is getting the image from the server again is because it is reusing the cells in the table view when they disappear so when they come back they are being loaded again so when you run your code for the cell that has already appeared you are doing `UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", IMAGE_URL, player.imagePath]]]]` to get your image again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to reload your image each time, you just cache your image. There are lot of option all around, one of them is NSCache or [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: no that;s not what i want. I want my tableCell to stop reloading

Comment: In iOS, creating a new view is expansive. So we use the reuseIdentifer mechanism, we create a little set of cells. And when a new cell becomes visible we fill it with the data. So you should use SDWebImage to download the image only once and serve it to the view when needed

Comment: Indeed its a cool thing but that is not what my question is. I am looking for my tableView cell to stop reloading when it is invisible and get itself visible

Comment: Depending on how big your data is for your uitableview if you are not reusing cells it will take a lot of memory up just to run that table view which is not recommended. The best option maybe to check the cache for the image first and if it doesn't exist then call from server and store it in cache.

Answer (score 1):

I do **not** recommend this:

You CAN (but should not) create your own array of cells with as many objects in it as there are rows in the table. Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can simply return the appropriate cell instead of reusing them. 
Technically there is nothing wrong with that.

For two handful of cells this should be fine. However, this concept will almost certainly lead to memory issues when the table gets larger.

You could as well maintain an array of (asynchronously loaded) images, reuse the cells properly and get back to your images array witin `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Howwever, this will not make much of a change with regard to the memory issue, because this would save memory for the cell views and subviews etc. but usually image data itself is quite memory consuming.

For unspecified numbers of rows, which may depend on user or business data or so and cannot be limited, there is no alternative to some smarter caching solution.